# How can I find matching values in two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, and I want to be able to compare the two and only return the values that match. For example both arrays have the value `cat` so that is what will be returned. I haven't found anything like this. What would be the best way to return similarities?

```
var array1 = ["cat", "sum","fun", "run"];
var array2 = ["bat", "cat","dog","sun", "hut", "gut"];

//if value in array1 is equal to value in array2 then return match: cat
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Naturally, my approach was to loop through the first array once and check the index of each value in the second array. If the index is `> -1`, then `push` it onto the returned array.

```
​Array.prototype.diff = function(arr2) {
    var ret = [];
    for(var i in this) {   
        if(arr2.indexOf(this[i]) > -1){
            ret.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
};
```

​
My solution doesn't use two loops like others do so it may run a bit faster. If you want to avoid using `for..in`, you can sort both arrays first to reindex all their values:

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(arr2) {
    var ret = [];
    this.sort();
    arr2.sort();
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i += 1) {
        if(arr2.indexOf(this[i]) > -1){
            ret.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
};
```

Usage would look like:

```
var array1 = ["cat", "sum","fun", "run", "hut"];
var array2 = ["bat", "cat","dog","sun", "hut", "gut"];

console.log(array1.diff(array2));
```

If you have an issue/problem with extending the Array prototype, you could easily change this to a function.

```
var diff = function(arr, arr2) {
```

And you'd change anywhere where the func originally said `this` to `arr2`.

Comment: `.indexOf()` just moves the loop.  The method loops through the target array internally. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: the `.indexOf()` function is probably faster than looping through all the array like done in the compatibility alternative.

Comment: Is indexOf() smart enough to use a binary search after the sort? Otherwise, this is O(N^2) since you are essentially doing nested looping due to indexOf() performing a linear scan. Even without that issue, why incur the linearithmic cost of sort when you can do this in linear time using an object as a hash table?

Comment: I've not heard of any ECMASCript engine that switches to a binary search on sorted arrays.  Would be an interesting optimization, including carrying a 'sorted' flag around with the array, but I wonder if there'd be enough call for it.

Comment: This is a bit late, but looks like the latest Chrome versions at least have much faster indexOf: http://jsperf.com/jquery-inarray-vs-underscore-indexof/43

Comment: Jeremy, great solution. I was debating myself between using two nested for loops vs. for-in with an embedded `indexOf()` lookup. However, I couldn't justify which of the two to use - both are readable to me, but one is more functional. My question to you is, how do you suppose your solution is faster when indexOf() uses a while loop anyways to do a strict comparison? Essentially, indexOf() just adds a layer of abstraction imo. See the indexOf polyfill code: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 497):

You can use :

```
const intersection = array1.filter(element => array2.includes(element));
```

Comment: This looks like the simplest and most concise answer. Not sure why it's not marked as being the right one.

Comment: That is because not all browsers will support it, unless you use a polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: As of late April 2019, only IE doesn't provide support.

Comment: ```const intersection = array1.filter(element => array2.indexOf(element) !== -1);``` without a polyfill.

Comment: `.includes()` is ES2016....meaning your ES6 transpiler will not transpile it.

Comment: @jota3 Hi, but how to keep the values unique in intersection. If array1 or array2 contains "cat" twice then my intersection array will also have "cat" 2 times. How to prevent that?

Comment: @Learner from ES6 you can use Set to filter out duplicated values and spread its values in an array like this : `const intersection = [...new Set(array1.filter(element => array2.includes(element)))];`

Comment: The really shocking part about this answer is that it's faster than the other solutions. A benchmark of phant0m, jeremy and jota3's answers shows consistent results. Measured in nanoseconds, phant0m: 107600, jeremy: 128300, jota3: 96800. The array's were a 91 5 letter word array compared to a 237 5 letter word array. No duplicates.

Comment: short and precise! thank you

Answer (score 36):

I found a slight alteration on what @jota3 suggested worked perfectly for me.

```
var intersections = array1.filter(e => array2.indexOf(e) !== -1);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It means you were using a javascript version anterior to ES2016 in which includes() has been added. indexOf() will work with any version.

Answer (score 18):

This function runs in `O(n log(n) + m log(m))` compared to `O(n*m)` (as seen in the other solutions with loops/`indexOf`) which can be useful if you are dealing with lots of values.

However, because neither `"a" > 1` nor `"a" < 1`, this only works for elements of the same type.

```
function intersect_arrays(a, b) {
    var sorted_a = a.concat().sort();
    var sorted_b = b.concat().sort();
    var common = [];
    var a_i = 0;
    var b_i = 0;

    while (a_i < a.length
           && b_i < b.length)
    {
        if (sorted_a[a_i] === sorted_b[b_i]) {
            common.push(sorted_a[a_i]);
            a_i++;
            b_i++;
        }
        else if(sorted_a[a_i] < sorted_b[b_i]) {
            a_i++;
        }
        else {
            b_i++;
        }
    }
    return common;
}
```

Example:

```
var array1 = ["cat", "sum", "fun", "hut"], //modified for additional match
    array2 = ["bat", "cat", "dog", "sun", "hut", "gut"];
intersect_arrays(array1, array2);
>> ["cat", "hut"]
```

Comment: The complexity is actually O(nlogn + mlogm + n + m), you forgot to consider the while loop while calculating.

Comment: @Partha `n` is subsumed by the faster growing `n logn`, the same applies for `m` and `m log n`.

Answer (score 13):

```
var array1  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var array3 = array2.filter(function(obj) { 
    return array1.indexOf(obj) !== -1; 
});
```

Comment: @Mr. 1.0 Please look into this efficient and clean code.

Comment: You may want to explain the above code.

Comment: Remove "," from the first line and add ";"

Comment: This is the easiest to understand

Answer (score 12):

Loop through the second array each time you iterate over an element in the first array, then check for matches.

```
var array1 = ["cat", "sum", "fun", "run"],
    array2 = ["bat", "cat", "dog", "sun", "hut", "gut"];

function getMatch(a, b) {
    var matches = [];

    for ( var i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
        for ( var e = 0; e < b.length; e++ ) {
            if ( a[i] === b[e] ) matches.push( a[i] );
        }
    }
    return matches;
}

getMatch(array1, array2); // ["cat"]
```

Comment: this uses the **length of array 1 * the length of array 2** amount of loops... 24 loops in this case.

Comment: no problem. it works, but its just extremely unnecessary and could potentially take forever to run. you can check out my answer for probably a better 1 loop solution

Answer (score 10):

You can use javascript function [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
As it says in MDN, it will return the ***first value*** that is true. If such an element is found, find *immediately* returns the value of that element. Otherwise, find returns `undefined`.

```js
var array1 = ["cat", "sum", "fun", "run", "cat"];
var array2 = ["bat", "cat", "dog", "sun", "hut", "gut"];

found = array1.find((val, index) => {
  console.log('index', index) // Stops at 0
  return array2.includes(val)
})
console.log(found)
```

Or use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which loops through every elements first, then give back the result to you.

```js
var array1 = ["cat", "sum", "fun", "run", "cat"];
var array2 = ["bat", "cat", "dog", "sun", "hut", "gut"];

found = array1.filter((val, index) => {
  console.log('index', index) // Stops at array1.length - 1
  return array2.includes(val)
})
console.log(found)
```

Answer (score 4):

use lodash

```
GLOBAL.utils = require('lodash')
var arr1 = ['first' , 'second'];
var arr2 = ['second '];

var result = utils.difference(arr1 , arr2);
console.log ( "result :" + result );
```

Answer (score 3):

Libraries like underscore and lodash have a utility method called `intersection` to find matches in arrays passed in. Take a look at: http://underscorejs.org/#intersection

Comment: Good point @EricLeschinski. I modified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Done as a answer so I can do formatting...

This is the the process you need to go through.  Looping through an array for the specifics.

```
create an empty array
loop through array1, element by element. {
  loop through array2, element by element {
    if array1.element == array2.element {
      add to your new array
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this uses the **length of array 1 * the length of array 2** amount of loops... 24 loops in this case.. it'd be better to just check if the index of the value in array1 is existent in array2 and then only 1 loop would be used. see my answer.

Comment: I thought about that.  `.indexOf()` still isn't supported everywhere, though it can be monkeypatched in easily enough... and `.indexOf()`, at least in the Mozilla monkeypatch version (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) still loops.  It just moves one of the loops to the `indexOf` function instead.

Comment: It's supported in all the major browsers, look at the compatibility table...

Comment: I'm well aware of where `indexOf` is, and is not, supported.  My _primary_ point is that your solution is still a two-loop solution.  One of the loops is just hidden.

Comment: it's much faster than actually using a hard coded loop though.

Comment: True -- but I doubt execution speed is the desired goal here.  This is a "Level 101" question, so the OP needs an answer that best describes the entire process without shortcuts.  Understanding _exactly_ what is going on is more important.

Answer (score 2):

If your values are non-null strings or numbers, you can use an object as a dictionary:

```
var map = {}, result = [], i;
for (i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
    map[array1[i]] = 1;
}

for (i = 0; i < array2.length; ++i) {
    if (map[array2[i]] === 1) {
        result.push(array2[i]);

        // avoid returning a value twice if it appears twice in array 2
        map[array2[i]] = 0;
    }
}

return result;
```

Comment: uses 2 loops. better than other solutions but you could bring it down to 1

Answer (score 2):

With some ES6:

```
let sortedArray = [];
firstArr.map((first) => {
  sortedArray[defaultArray.findIndex(def => def === first)] = first;
});
sortedArray = sortedArray.filter(v => v);
```

This snippet also sorts the *firstArr* based on the order of the *defaultArray*

like:

```
let firstArr = ['apple', 'kiwi', 'banana'];
let defaultArray = ['kiwi', 'apple', 'pear'];
...
console.log(sortedArray);
// ['kiwi', 'apple'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate on  array1 and find the indexof element present in array2.

```
var array1 = ["cat", "sum","fun", "run"];
var array2 = ["bat", "cat","sun", "hut", "gut"];
var str='';
for(var i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
        if(array2.indexOf(array1[i]) != -1){
           str+=array1[i]+' ';
       };
    }
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Only code is just not make sense. provide explanation for your answer what you giving to OP.