# Most effective and elegant way to find matching Strings in two arrays in Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have 2 string arrays:

```
var X = ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    Y = ['B', 'C', 'D'];
```

I need to create an array `Z`, such that Z = A ∩ B

```
Z = ['B', 'C'];
```

Z contains the strings that are both in `X` and `Y`.

I've done it this way:

```
A.forEach(function(i) {
  B.forEach(function(j) {
    if (i === j) Z.push(i);
  });
});
```

Any suggestions / comments?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433604/how-can-i-find-matching-values-in-two-arrays

Comment: There is no magic to this, you would have to iterate through elements, if you are using any helper function then that function internally would be doing loop as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd better use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
['A', 'B', 'C'].filter(function(c) {
    return ['B', 'C', 'D'].indexOf(c) > -1;
});
```

Comment: Right, using `.indexOf()` was my initial approach. The problem is that if array has 2 similar words like "INTERNATIONAL and "NATIONAL" - both of them appear as matching :)

Comment: It shouldn't, as you're mixing two different `indexOf` methods: [for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [for strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Comment: Works like a charm. What are the advantages of using `filter` instead of my solution?

Comment: @martynas I see no particular advantages... both should be rather fast. Maybe `filter` approach is slightly shorter and clearer.

Comment: Hmm... not sure how filter works but my method might have redundant operations.

Comment: @martynas It creates a new array with elements that match the condition given in the callback. In your case you use two callbacks for `forEach`, while here there is only one, as another is implicitly implemented inside `indexOf` method.