# Jquery to compare and return string arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hi I am developing one jquery application. I am trying to compare the two arrays. For example,

```
Firstarray=["Mike","Jack"];
SecondArray=["Mike","Jack","Andy","Cruz"];
```

Whenever we compare above two arrays I want to return the strings which exists in both arrays or which are common to both arrays!

I tried as below. This piece of code is not working.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Firstarray.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < SecondArray.length; j++) {
     if (Firstarray[i] == SecondArray[j]) {
        alert('found ' + SecondArray[j]);
        return;
     }
   }
}
```

Can anyone help me in this regards! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `indexOf()` function

```js
Firstarray=["Mike","Jack"];
SecondArray=["Mike","Jack","Andy","Cruz"];
var result = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < Firstarray.length; i++) {
  if(SecondArray.indexOf(Firstarray[i])>=0){
    result.push(Firstarray[i]);
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: Whenever i go to hit that button, it says you can accept answer in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) along with some *ES6* flavor thrown in - see demo below:

```js
var firstArray=["Mike","Jack"];
var secondArray=["Mike","Jack","Andy","Cruz"];

var result = secondArray.filter(a => firstArray.some(b => a === b));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

check this [How can I find matching values in two arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433604/how-can-i-find-matching-values-in-two-arrays)

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(arr2) {
var ret = [];
this.sort();
arr2.sort();
for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i += 1) {
    if(arr2.indexOf( this[i] ) > -1){
        ret.push( this[i] );
    }
}
return ret;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var FirstArray=["Mike","Jack"];
var SecondArray=["Mike","Jack","Andy","Cruz"];
var commonArray = Array();
var count=0;

for (var i=0; i<FirstArray.length; i++) {
  for (var j=0;j< SecondArray.length;j++) {
    if (FirstArray[i] == SecondArray[j]){
      commonArray[count]=FirstArray[i];
      count++;
    }
  }
}

console.log(commonArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing few things in your code :

```
var Firstarray=["Mike","Jack"];
var SecondArray=["Mike","Jack","Andy","Cruz"];
var matchedData = [];


for (var i = 0; i < Firstarray.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < SecondArray.length; j++) {
                    if (Firstarray[i] == SecondArray[j]) {
                        matchedData.push(SecondArray[j]);

                    }
                }
            }
            alert(matchedData);
```

working fiddle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/o3brcsvw/

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var Firstarray=["Mike","Jack"];
var SecondArray=["Mike","Jack","Andy","Cruz"];
var matchedData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Firstarray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < SecondArray.length; j++) {
        if (Firstarray[i] == SecondArray[j]) {
            //alert('found ' + SecondArray[j]);
            matchedData.push(SecondArray[j]);
        }
    }
}
return matchedData;
```