# JavaScript: Match any element within array and return the match

Tags: javascript

I need to match any item within 2 array's and then return the value of that match. For example:

```
let arr1 = [ 'grid-view' ,'list-view' ];
let arr2 = [ 'test', 'list-view' ];
```

From the above I would get `list-view` returned.

This is what I have at the moment, however it returns true, whereas I need the actual match. Trying avoid doing horrid big loops and having too much code.

```js
let switches = document.querySelectorAll('[data-switch]');
let switchesClasses = [].slice.call(switches).map(x => x.dataset.switchClass);

const found = Array.from(document.querySelector('.test').classList).some(r => switchesClasses.includes(r));

console.log(found);
```

```html
<div class="showroom-layout-toggle" data-switch-group="showroom_layout" data-switch-target=".test" data-switch-cookie>
  <button class="grid-toggle" data-switch data-switch-class="grid-view">Grid</button>
  <button class="grid-toggle" data-switch data-switch-class="list-view">List</button>
</div>

<div class="test list-view">Hello</div>
```

Comment: This has already been answered Link to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46957719/11828927

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace "some" with "filter", you'll get an array of the matched classes.

So, with your test arrays, that would look like this:

```
let found = arr2.filter(r => arr1.includes(r));
console.log(found); // ["list-view"]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. ***It returns a Boolean value***.

Instead of `some()` try with [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
let arr1 = [ 'grid-view' ,'list-view' ];
let arr2 = [ 'test', 'list-view' ];

let switches = document.querySelectorAll('[data-switch]');
let switchesClasses = [].slice.call(switches).map(x => x.dataset.switchClass);

const found = Array.from(document.querySelector('.test').classList).filter(r => switchesClasses.includes(r));
console.log(found);
```

```html
<div class="showroom-layout-toggle" data-switch-group="showroom_layout" data-switch-target=".test" data-switch-cookie>
  <button class="grid-toggle" data-switch data-switch-class="grid-view">Grid</button>
  <button class="grid-toggle" data-switch data-switch-class="list-view">List</button>
</div>

<div class="test list-view">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find` instead of `.some`:

```js
let switches = document.querySelectorAll('[data-switch]');
let switchesClasses = [].slice.call(switches).map(x => x.dataset.switchClass);

const found = Array.from(document.querySelector('.test').classList)
  .find(r => switchesClasses.includes(r));

console.log(found);
```

```html
<div class="showroom-layout-toggle" data-switch-group="showroom_layout" data-switch-target=".test" data-switch-cookie>
  <button class="grid-toggle" data-switch data-switch-class="grid-view">Grid</button>
  <button class="grid-toggle" data-switch data-switch-class="list-view">List</button>
</div>

<div class="test list-view">Hello</div>
```

Not that it matters much for inputs this small, but for this general situation I'd prefer to make a Set to make the computational complexity `O(n)` instead of `O(n^2)`:

```js
const switchesClasses = new Set(
  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-switch]'),
    x => x.dataset.switchClass
  )
);


const found = Array.from(document.querySelector('.test').classList)
  .find(r => switchesClasses.has(r));

console.log(found);
```

```html
<div class="showroom-layout-toggle" data-switch-group="showroom_layout" data-switch-target=".test" data-switch-cookie>
  <button class="grid-toggle" data-switch data-switch-class="grid-view">Grid</button>
  <button class="grid-toggle" data-switch data-switch-class="list-view">List</button>
</div>

<div class="test list-view">Hello</div>
```