# how to get intersection between twos list in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

inside a get request fucntion to mysql db and After two awaits on promises to get two lists (tab1  and tab2) filled, i want to get the intersection between them. tab1 and tab2 are lists of strings.

```
const app = express();
var intersectionBetween = function(a1,a2){
  return  a1.filter(function(n) { return a2.indexOf(n) !== -1;});
};
app.get('/getPackages', async (req, res) => {
  var tab1= []
  var tab2= []
  const promiseIntersection = (a1, a2) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej)=> {
      intersectionBetween(a1, a2, function (err, resultsss){
        if (err) rej(err);
        return res(resultsss)
      });
    })
  }
  const intersectionb = await promiseIntersection(tab1, tab2);
  console.log("efe",intersectionb)
  res.send('Posts fetched...');

});


app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Express server is runnig at port: 3000"))
```

I wanted to get the intersection but when I go in the browser under '/getPackages' the browser runs forever without returning anything. Can anyone help?

Comment: just get the intersection in the SQL query

Comment: `intersectionBetween` just accepts two parameter, but when invoking it you're passing three parameters, so eventually `res or rej` will not get called at all

Comment: @pilchard the source of the table is not the same. the first one is coming from db and the second from svn repo

Comment: @CodeManiac how do you suggest correcting this?

Comment: @sffgsfgs I assume you need to pass results only if you found intersection, so if you found intersection resolve promise, if not then just reject promise.

Comment: @CodeManiac can you please write your suggestion? I didn't get it. Thanks!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46957719/7927294 check this out

Comment: @sffgsfgs get those two arrays from your db first and do the traversal in your nodejs runtime, code is very complex for the problem you are trying to solve here

Comment: @sffgsfgs , you are resolving promise in the callback method of ```intersectionBetween``` method which you are not invoking. So the promise will get never resolved.

Answer (score 0):

After two awaits on promises to get two lists (tab1 and tab2) filled, you can directly call it and get intersection. There is nothing async.

```
app.get('/getPackages', async (req, res) => {
        var tab1= []
        var tab2= []
        const intersectionb = intersectionBetween(tab1, tab2);
        console.log("efe",intersectionb)
        res.send('Posts fetched...');
    
    });
```

Comment: thank you. That's what I tried before this solution but i get an empty array which shouldn't be the case

Comment: I don't know what is empty array. From my test given 2 arrays of strings the function works fine, unless there are no duplicated strings in them. Could you show us how to get tab1 and tab2, and what's the value inside them?